# Image Gallery using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I'm unable to display images which are saved in MYSQL database
**Here is my view code which upload file**

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('Welcome/do_upload');?>
<input name="file" size="40" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
```

**this my controller file**

```
public function do_upload()
    {
        $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '3000';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file'))
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($this->input->post());
            print_r($error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data('file'));
            echo "Upload";
            $this->Blog->insert_images($this->upload->data());
             $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        }
    }
```

**this is my model file** 
this file is first insert image then show all the images from database

```
public function insert_images($image_data = array()){
      $data = array(
          'i_id' => "NULL",
          'i_s' => $image_data['full_path']
      );
        $img=$this->db->get('images')->result();
        foreach($img as $i){
            ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $i->i_s?>">

            <?php
            }

        }
```

any help will be Highly appreciated

Comment: Never put HTML in model. Even you don't need to put html in controller. Stick HTML with your view files. If you want to have path of image just uploaded you should do that in controller already. From model just return boolean wether insert is successful or not. In case it is successful, you can use path of uploaded image since you have it in controller firstly.

Comment: @Tpojka agree with you that view files are place in view folder instead of model, but it is not a problem in my case I'm unable to fetch images from database once i get the images so it is not a problem to whether shown in views or model..              have you find any error in my fetch query???

Comment: Check your model again. You didn't use `insert()` method at all. But you are trying to get data from table? You have to insert something first to be able to pull it out.

Comment: @Tpojka yeah i already insert data into my table and that work perfectly but I'm unable to display images.. I get path like E://xamp/site....       but i didn't get http://localhost/site/img.jpg

Answer (score 1):

**The problem is saving the path in the database**

```
$data = array(
          'i_id' => "NULL",
          'i_s' => $image_data['full_path']
      );
```

**replace this code by this**

```
$data = array(
          'i_id' => "NULL",
          'i_s' => $image_data['file_name']
      );
```

and to display the images from database write this code

```
<?php foreach($im as $imd){?>
<img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/'.$imd->i_s);?>">
<?php }?>
```

Comment: I think you are saving wrong string in DB. Instead of saving relative path or slug, he is saving full absolute path which is unuseful for preview in browser.

Comment: Did this fixed your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to store file absolute path. You should store relative path of image in database. Relative to

```
FCPATH
```

For example: if your settings are

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/site/';
```

, stored string in DB should be something like

```
img.jpg
```

When you want to see it in browser, you would call

```
echo base_url('img.jpg');
```

Comment: my base_url shows when i echo it ** http://127.0.0.1/Frame_Work/Blog_SIte(torrent)/**                                                                                         $data = array(
          'i_id' => "NULL",
          'i_s' => $image_data['full_path']
      );
      print_r($data);                                                                                               Array ( [i_id] => NULL [i_s] => E:/xampp/htdocs/Frame_Work/Blog_SIte(torrent)/uploads/215483d85.jpg )

Comment: It is unreadable here. Edit your question and add it there in preformatted tags.

Comment: my issue is resolve the problem is saving the path in the database

Comment: Why do you use parenthesis in base URL? Any particular reason? If no, use only lowercases. Delete `(torrent)` part and try `http://localhost/frame_work/blog_site`. Tell me if you are getting same result with localhost as for IP. Check what is set for `$config['base_url']` in `APPPATH.'config/config.php'`.